# $\ X, Y \sim Geo(p) $ find pdf of $\ R = |X-Y| $

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\ X, Y \sim Geo(p) $ independent variables. Let  $\ R = |X - Y| $ . Find pdf of $\ R $

I don't understand the last equality:

$$\ P\{R=j\} = P\{|X-Y|=j\} = P\{X-Y = j\} + P\{Y-X = j \} = 2P\{Y-X = j\}  $$

Why does $\ P\{X-Y = j\} + P \{Y-X =j\} = 2P\{Y-X=j\} $ ?

Comment: Not pdf, it is a pmf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by symmetry. Since $X$ and $Y$ are iid, $X-Y$ and $Y-X$ have the same distribution (they are both "difference of two independent $Geo(p)$ random variables" in distribution). Hence for any $j$, we have $P(X-Y = j) = P(Y-X = j)$.